# CUDA gridDim, blockDim are always user defined?

Tags: c++, c, cuda

When I pass the grid size and thread count at kernel call, will these values be placed in gridDim and blockDim always and exactly as I passed them?

And, moreover, will blockIdx and threadIdx always respect these limits?

In other words, calling

```
kernel<<<5, 7>>>()
```

always results in having, in the kernel,

```
gridDim.x == 5 && blockIdx.x < gridDim.x
blockDim.x == 7 && threadIdx.x < blockDim.x
```

the above conditions to hold? (And equally with 2D and 3D sizes and index?)

I know this may sound silly as question, but I'm wondering if CUDA is allowed to ignore this limits for resource allocation and thus the programmer is always required to check.

Hoping it's clear, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you start your kernel in the dimension <<<5,7>>> it will have 5 blocks and 7 threads per block.
Note that you are most efficient if you operate in the bounds of your GPU. You should use the warpsize as read from the device properties to get the maximum speed out of your card. Use a lot of threads as needed, but the blocks should be a multiple of your warpsize.

CUDA itself does not change your threads / blocks to another size, so you should be fine with the addressing.

Comment: Thanks, also for the performance tip. Have you any reference for the answer, please?

Comment: To add to this, if for any reason the driver can't satisfy your request (e.g. you ask for 10K threads/block which is not possible, c.f. CUDA C Programming Guide) then the kernel launch will fail and the next API call will return the error.

Comment: The references I used is the CUDA Programming guide, and other SO questions I encountered on this. I have no direct reference for this question though.